# Switchee regex for numbers

Tags: switchee, regex

Trying to get switchee to work with a regex check against a URL segment.

For example following URL check if segment 2 is numeric:

```
/property/123
```

Using:

```
{exp:switchee variable = "{segment_2}"}
    {case value="#[0-9]+#"}
        IS A NUMBER
    {/case}
{/exp:switchee}
```

However this isn't working. Any thoughts/suggestions?

Cheers

Cole

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the `parse` parameter to `inward` if you want to discard the content of the unmatched cases before parsing them or you are using a module or plugin tag as a parameter.

The RegEx you're using, `/[0-9]+/`, will match strings containing a number, not being one.

Please, try:

```
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_2}" parse="inward"}
    {case value="#^\d+$#"}
        IS A NUMBER
    {/case}
    {case default="yes"}
        NOT A NUMBER
    {/case}
{/exp:switchee}
```

`^\d+$` will match just numbers.

Comment: Thanks - this seems to have worked when the switchee condition is at root but not when using nested conditions. Any thoughts why that might be?

Comment: I can't imagine a reason for this. Can you show me some code?

Answer (score 0):

Add parse="inward" to switchee:

```
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_2}" parse="inward"}
    {case value="#[0-9]+#"}
        IS A NUMBER
    {/case}
    {case default="yes"}
        NOT A NUMBER
    {/case}
{/exp:switchee}
```